# PayPal Integration with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal

im following "Rails Casts ep 141" for integrate a basic paypal into my project, but it fails, and i can't found the issue.

Here is my cart model (using gem 'acts_as_shopping_cart)

```
class ShoppingCart < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_shopping_cart

  def self.paypal_url
    values ={
        :business => 'admin@ing.com',
        :cmd => '_cart',
        :upload => 1,
        :invoice => id
    }
    @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
        values.merge!({
            "amount_#{index+1}" => item.precio,
            "item_name_#{index+1}" => item.nombre,
            })
    end
    "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?"+values.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
  end

end
```

and where i called the method paypal_url is here

```
<title>Tu carrito</title>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="collection with-header">
      <li class="collection-header"><h4>Tu lista de productos</h4></li>
      <% @shopping_cart.shopping_cart_items.each do |sc| %>
        <li class="collection-item"><div><%= link_to Article.find(sc.item_id).nombre, article_path(Article.find(sc.item_id)) %>
                  <%= link_to shopping_carts_path(:product_id => sc.item_id), method: :delete, data:{ confirm: "Quitar este elemento del carrito?" }, class: "right" do%>
                  <i class="material-icons">delete</i>
                  <%end%></li>
      <%end%>
    </ul>
    <%= link_to "Checkout", @shopping_cart.paypal_url() %>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

When i try to enter in my cart's Shows View, it gives to me this message

```
undefined method `paypal_url' for #<ShoppingCart:0x007fd00d3e9358>
```

How could i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define paypal_url as an instance method, not a class method.
Like so:

```
def paypal_url
    values ={
        :business => 'admin@ing.com',
        :cmd => '_cart',
        :upload => 1,
        :invoice => id
    }
    shopping_cart_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
        values.merge!({
            "amount_#{index+1}" => item.precio,
            "item_name_#{index+1}" => item.nombre,
            })
    end
    "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?"+values.map{|k,v| "#{k}=#{v}"}.join("&")
end
```